# Facebook linking issues with iOS project

Tags: objective-c, ios, facebook

I guess I'm not linking the Facebook SDK properly with my project. Here's the error I get:

```
clang: error: no such file or directory: '/Users/username/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Whatto-fotukpkslfnxvzbjmykxitdwkyds/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libfacebook_ios_sdk.a'
```

This is an ARC iOS project. Any help would be great.

fyi: the Facebook libfacebook_ios_sdk.a library is red in the Build Phases/Link Binary With Libraries area under Project targets.

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest dragging and dropping the library in the Project Navigator, then doing a clean followed by a build.

Comment: same thing. I even restarted Xcode. Should the libfacebook_ios_sdk.a file be red?

Comment: @hanumanDev mmm, no it should not be red, does it build for device?, it is possible the static library is only for device and not for simulator.

Comment: I've had it build for a non ARC project without a problem on the simulator. I have JSON files for Google Places API and ran into duplicate problems. and issues since then.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you've added the facebook-ios-sdk Xcode project into your project... try just importing the contents of the FBConnect group. No need to include the project files.